# Is there a way to detect if Chrome's Devtools are using dark mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Javascript from a **PAGE** and not from the devtools themselves is there currently a way to determine if Chrome's devtools are using dark mode instead of the "normal mode"?

I did find a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=608869#c4) with a comment about this but it looks like that only relates to Chrome extensions.

Comment: Yes. If you open the element inspector on the dev tools, the class `-theme-with-dark-background` is attached to the document body. Look for that. From there you can write some javascript to get the answer you want.

Comment: Is that class accessible from a site or just the devtools themselves though?

Comment: The devtools themselves are an inspectable browser window. As for how you'd access this info from, say, another context like a chrome extension or the parent chrome window, I don't know if that'd be possible.

Comment: So that doesn't answer this at all. I already mentioned extensions can access this via a built in object.

Comment: Well, it does provide an answer if you have the devtools up for the devtools themselves. You didn't specify what context you were trying to get this information in.

Comment: It should be expected that it wasn't from devtools. If I have them open and can see it's in dark mode and/or can access the js var that I specifically mentioned then why would I want an answer that just repeats when I had already said?

Answer (score 7):

No, it's **not** available from a **page**.

It is only available for extensions in javascript via:

`chrome.devtools.panels.themeName`

> The name of the color theme set in user's DevTools settings. Possible values: `default` (the default) and `dark`.
>
> Since Chrome 59.

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels

So it's technically possible to write an chrome-extension that reads the value and then exposes that to the page via a class or javascript variable.
But requiring your visitors to install an extension for detecting  dark mode just isn't practical.